# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. not solving

Tags: android, android-studio, library-project

I have possibly tried all the solutions regarding this issue.
The full error is: Error:Execution failed for task "

```
':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

"
I am posting my build.gradle scripts: 
Script name: RajawaliCardBoardExample-master

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.



buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

name: Module:app >>

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.eje_c.rajawalicardboard"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':rajawalicardboard')
    compile project(':lib_panorama_max')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

name: Module:lib_panorama_max >>

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    extension 'jar'
    from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
        options.debug = true
        options.debugOptions.debugLevel = "source,lines,vars"
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}


dependencies {
    compile files('libs/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/android.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'build/native-libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

name: Module:Rajawali >>

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
        jumboMode = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

name: Module:rajawalicardboard >>

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
        jumboMode = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile project(':rajawali')
}
```

Please help to sort it out! :(

Comment: try putting `multiDexEnabled true` in `Module:app` too..

Comment: nothing happened sir. @ShreeKrishna

Answer (score 1):

At first you should add

```
 defaultConfig
 {

    // Enabling multidex support.
       multiDexEnabled true
 }
```

Open `Module:app` .You missing `multiDexEnabled true` in here .

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.eje_c.rajawalicardboard"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
```

Read Official Document about **[MultiDex](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html)**

Comment: for test case remove `multiDexEnabled true` from app

Comment: omit `multiDexEnabled true`  from `Module:Rajawali`

Comment: I have removed multiDexEnabled true from module:app and module:rajawali but still the problem exists! :(

Comment: IntelliJ sir, please solve this. 3 days have passed and still the issue is not resolved :( :(

Comment: @IndranilDutta okay . call `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'`  instead of `.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'`

Comment: sir, it is saying plugin is too old.

Comment: then `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'`

Comment: to use this classpath I was required to use gradle 2.10 but I updated to the latest of 2.12. Still the error exists. :'(

Comment: Then move back your previous

Answer (score 0):

The option 1 was adding `multiDexEnabled true`
But you told it didn't work at all, you can try excluding `group group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'` now which means in the compilation for example change

```
compile project(':rajawalicardboard')
```

To

```
compile project(':rajawalicardboard'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    }
```

Don't only try on this, do the same in `compile project(':lib_panorama_max')` if only the changes above didn't work. Try removing `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` too.

Comment: after doing all these this error generates:

Error:(39, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'RajawaliCardboardExample-master' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: Sir please rly :( :(

Comment: If that shown then don't use this method to that.. Use this method in which this error won't be raised..

Comment: I didn't understand. Show me the applicable code please.

Comment: Did android studio pointed to any lines after clicking the error ?

Comment: no sir..
actually cardboardviewer and panorama use same library codes and both need the library individually. That's library confliction is happening. :(

Comment: I am really unfamiliar with `rajawalicardboard` and don't know what `panorama_max` is and how their gradles are configured. But may be these all because of conflict compilation. I am really sorry brother... Intellij bro may help you on this..

Comment: @ShreeKrishna You are true .Very complex Gradle

Comment: Actually rajawalicardboard is nothing but the feature to view 360 panorama using cardboardviewer. You can find an app of cardboardviewer from google play also and lib_panorama_max is the library project of 360 panorama. 
both are library project downloaded from open source.
Problem is lib_panorama can work in Eclipse but rajawalicardboard can only work in android studio. that's why for a project development both the library project need to work together. Now, I am helpless. Me and my team leader are worried! :(

Comment: bro, Really sad to hear.... if you are really in such a trouble then send me whole project zipping..I will try to resolve as possible as I can....

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Sir this a Google Drive link for the zipped project. Thanks for your kind reply :)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzT1z5zAgv_YcFFsZURwV2g1N3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya bro, He seems really in trouble any help will be so appreciated if you got time to look at his project ...

Comment: @ShreeKrishna you will need JDK 7 to compile this project. Bad class magic will go away. Right click Project. Open module Settings>SDK location. set it to JDK 7. cause AS still not support JDK 8 :(

Comment: I tried everything possible bro, Downloaded different versions of gradles and tried changing paths removing each as possible....... But couldn't..

Comment: @ShreeKrishna thank you for your time :) Very unfortunate project!! :(